# Find maximize value of this expression

Tags: inequality, optimization

Let $a;b;c \in [0;2]$

Find maximum value of: $P=ab(a^2-b^2)+bc(b^2-c^2)+ca(c^2-a^2)$

After some factoring, I found:

$P=(a-b)(b-c)(a-c)(a+b+c)$

Then square it: $P^2=(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2(a+b+c)^2$

Now $P^2$ be a symmetric expression. But it' still hard. Can someone help, please? Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like a old Putnam problem or a national math olympiad problem of some country recently.

Comment: it is homogeneous; there is no need to square it. The extrema must occur on the faces of the cube, so at least one of $a,b,c$ must be equal to $2.$ So, with $0 \leq a,b \leq 2$ still, what happens with $P=ab(a^2-b^2)  +2b(b^2-4) +2a(4-a^2) \; ? \; $  Apparently $(a-b)(a-2)(b-2)(a+b-2) $

Answer (score 5):

Let $P=f(a,b,c)$ and note that for $k\le \min\{2-a,2-b,2-c\}$

$$f(a+k,b+k,c+k)\ge f(a,b,c)$$

Thus, we can choose $a=2$ (WLOG). Now, we need to maximize

\begin{align}f(2,b,c)&=2b(4-b^2)+bc(b^2-c^2)+2c(c^2-4)
\\
&=2b(4-b^2)+c(b^3-8)+c^3(2-b)
\\
&=2b(4-b^2)+c(b-2)(b^2+2b+4-c^2)
\end{align}

Observe that $$b-2\le 0$$

$$b^2+2b+(4-c^2)\ge 0$$

Thus,

$$f(2,b,0)\ge f(2,b,c)$$

Now, we need to maximize

$$f(2,b,0)=2b(4-b^2)$$

Candidates are boundary values and values that make the first order equal to $0$. Checking all values gives us

$$\frac{32}{3\sqrt{3}}=f(2,\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}},0)\ge f(a,b,c)$$

Remember $f$ is symmetric.

Done!

Answer (score 2):

Since $K=[0,2]^3$ is a compact set, and $P=P(a,b,c)$ is continuous on $K$ with real values, there is a maximal value. It is taken at some point $(a^*,b^*,c^*)$, which is

- (i) either in the interior $(0,2)^3$ of $K$, which is then a local extremal value, so that in this point
  $$
  \tag{$\dagger$}
  P'_a=P'_b=P'_c=0\ ,$$
- (ii) or at the boundary, and then by symmetry, we may and do assume $c^*=0$. Else if $c^*=2$ we replace $a^*$, $b^*$, $c^*$ by $2-a^*$, $2-b^*$, $2-c^*$ and possibly also exchange $a^*\leftrightarrow b^*$ to have a positive value.

We consider both cases individually.

(i) The system $(\dagger)$ becomes:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
0 &=3(a^2 - 6b^2 - 6bc - 6c^2)(b - c)
\ ,\\
0 &= 3(b^2 - 6c^2 - 6ca - 6a^2)(c - a)
\ ,\\
0 &= 3(c^2 - 6a^2 - 6ab - 6b^2)(a - b)
\ .
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
If $a\ne b\ne c\ne a$, then all factors of the shape $(a^2 - 6b^2 - 6bc - 6c^2)$ with the cyclicly permuted cousins must vanish. In sum we obtain $11a^2 + 11b^2 + 11c^2 + 6ab +6ac + 6ca=0$. So $3(a-b)^2+3(b-c)^2+3(c-a)^2+5(a^2+b^2+c^2)=0$. This gives $a=b=c=0$, which is not an interior point. So at least two values among $a,b,c$ coincide, we may and do assume by symmetry that $a=b$. Then from the other two equations, since $a^2-6c^2-6ca-6a^2\le 0$ - with equality at the boundary of $K$ - we get $a=b=c$, so in such a point $P$ is zero, which does not correspond to a maximal value. (For instance, the point $(2,1,0)$ leads to a bigger value.)  So there is no interior maximal point.

(ii) Me may and do assume $c=0$, so the function to be maximized on $L=[0,2]^2$ is
$$
Q(a,b)=ab(a-b)(a+b)=ab(a^2-b^2)=a^3b-b^3a\ .
$$
Again, this function is defined on a compact set $L$, is real valued, so there is a maximal value taken at some point $(a^*,b^*)\in L$. And we distinguish the two cases, (ii,1) the point is an interior point, and (ii,2) the point is a boundary point. For an interior point, we must have $Q'_a=Q'_b=0$, but the corresponding system $3a^2b-b^3=0=-(3b^2a-a^3)$ has no solution with $ab\ne 0$. So the case (ii,1) is excluded. The maximum is thus taken in some point $(a^*,b^*)$ with either $a^*=2$, case (ii,2,A), or $b^*=0$, case (ii,2,B).

The case (ii,2,B) is immediately excluded, since $Q(a,0)=0$.

The case (ii,2,A) leads to the function $R(b)=2b(2-b)(2+b)=8b-2b^3$, which should be maximized on the interval $J=[0,2]$. At the boundary the values are zero, and in the interior the values are $>0$, so we have an interior point $b^*\in J$ with maximal value for $R$, and its is a solution of the equation $R'=0$, so $8-6b^2=0$. So
$$
b^*=\sqrt{\frac 86}=\frac 2{\sqrt 3}\ .
$$
So the maximal value of $P$ is reached in the point
$$
(a^*,b^*,c^*)=\left(2,\frac 2{\sqrt 3},0\right)
$$
and
$$
\max P=
P(a^*,b^*,c^*)
=
Q(a^*,b^*)
=R(b^*)
=2b^*(4-{b^*}^2)
=2\cdot\frac 2{\sqrt 3}\left(4-\frac 43\right)
=\frac{32}{3\sqrt 3}
\approx 6.158402871356\dots\ .
$$

---

Computer checks:

Sage code:

```
sage: def minusP(point): a, b, c = point; return -(a*b*(a^2 - b^2) + b*c*(b^2 - c^2) + c*a*(c^2 - a^2))
sage: point = minimize_constrained(minusP, [[0,2], [0,2], [0,2]], (2, 1, 0))
sage: point
(2.0, 1.1547005363453975, 0.0)
sage: 2/sqrt(3.)
1.15470053837925
sage: -minusP( point )
6.1584028713560075
sage: 32. / 3 / sqrt(3.)
6.15840287135601
```

The twist via `minimize_constrained` was needed since there is no `maximize_constrained`.

Mathematica (TM): [Link to wolframalpha code](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize%20%28a-b%29*%28a-c%29*%28b-c%29*%28a%2Bb%2Bc%29%20on%200%3C%3D%20a%3C%3D%202%2C0%3C%3D%20b%3C%3D%202%2C0%3C%3D%20c%3C%3D%202%20)

Comment: How did you get the system in the first case?  I differentiated *P* with respect to *a*, and I got 3*a*²(*b*−*c*)−*b*³+*c*³ = (3*a*²−*b*²−*bc*−*c*²)(*b*−*c*).  Why is there a '6'? https://wolframalpha.com/input?i=partial+derivative+ab%28a%5E2-b%5E2%29%2Bbc%28b%5E2-c%5E2%29%2Bca%28c%5E2-a%5E2%29+with+respect+to+a